# JWT forgery by an internal attacker

Tags: authorization, jwt, jws

I have an authorization server that generate JWTs, the JWTs are signed with a private key (RS256) stored on a hardware security module. The tokens are generated only after a successful authentication.

What measures can be taken to prevent internal actors from using the authorization server to forge JWTs ?

Answer (score 1):

- **Network segmentation** for the HSM is a good measure.
- **Principle of Least Privilege** for who can authenticate to the HSM as well.